# When i changing orientation my view's height and width are not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, orientation

I have use one view in sub view of Default view. I am trying to set its height and width same as super view, when it change orientation.First when app loads portrait mode,then this sub view take perfect height-width but when second time we change to portrait mode it is not change height and width.
In Load:-

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Method:-

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            NSLog(@"Portrait");
            NSLog(@"View Height %f",self.view.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"View Width%f",self.view.frame.size.width);

            view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            NSLog(@"View1 Height %f",view1.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"View1 Width%f",view1.frame.size.width);

            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            NSLog(@" LanScapRight");


             view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);



            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

            NSLog(@" LandScapLeft");

            view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


        default:
            view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


            NSLog(@"Default");

            //view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);


            break;
    };
}
```

Output:-(Problem)

```
2016-02-20 01:29:15.907 Editing[4999:95632] Portrait
[![2016-02-20 01:29:15.910 Editing\[4999:95632\] View Height 568.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:15.910 Editing\[4999:95632\] View Width320.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:15.911 Editing\[4999:95632\] View1 Height 568.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:15.912 Editing\[4999:95632\] View1 Width320.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:39.090 Editing\[4999:95632\] LanScapRight
2016-02-20 01:29:40.364 Editing\[4999:95632\] Default
2016-02-20 01:29:41.645 Editing\[4999:95632\] LandScapLeft
2016-02-20 01:29:41.646 Editing\[4999:95632\] Default
2016-02-20 01:29:43.316 Editing\[4999:95632\] Portrait
2016-02-20 01:29:43.317 Editing\[4999:95632\] View Height 320.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:43.317 Editing\[4999:95632\] View Width568.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:43.317 Editing\[4999:95632\] View1 Height 320.000000
2016-02-20 01:29:43.318 Editing\[4999:95632\] View1 Width568.000000]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a valid reason to not use autolayout?

Comment: smit is your problem solved ?

Comment: @elio.d yes i want to place calendar at center.

Comment: @KishoreKumar no i have tried but dose not get any solution

Comment: @Smit Saraiya: Centering the calendar is absolutelly not against autolayouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather usual task to update UI due to interface orientation change, thus there is a well supported method to do this.

**SOLUTION 1:**

If you are using a frame-based layout (as in your example code) it is recommended to put your frame setting code into the view's `layoutSubviews` as Jan Greve commented. To do this you have to subclass UIView. The `layoutSubviews` method will be called every time when the bounds of the view has changed, thus you don't have to observe notification about interface orientations, and you will also be able to react to other size-changing events e.g. multitasking split view. Here is a super-minimal example how to subclass UIView and implement the layouting:

//  MyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView

@property (strong) UIView* view1;
@property (strong) UIView* calendar;

@end
```

//  MyView.m

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self addSubview:self.view1];
        self.calendar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
        self.calendar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view1 addSubview:self.calendar];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.view1.frame = self.bounds;
    self.calendar.center = self.view1.center;
}

@end
```

If you set a MyView instance to the viewcontroller's view property it just works.

**SOLUTION 2:**

Solution 1 can be used in general, but in your particular case layouting can be done through autoresizingmasks. (Here I have to reffer to Jan Greve again, who recommended this in his answer.) Now you don't need to subclass UIView everything can be handle from the viewcontroller. You can insert something like this into `viewDidLoad`

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
view1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UIView* calendar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
calendar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[view1 addSubview:calendar];
calendar.center = view1.center;
calendar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Your Second solution is works.. Thanks brother.. Using this no need to set any orientation methods..

Comment: But it will hide status bar.

Comment: Hiding the status bar in landscape mode on an iPhone is the default behaviour (check Safari e.g.). It's independent from the view layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Use this on above switch case, this code is used for reloading the
view, so that you will get updated view width and height.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the view to have exactly the bounds of it's superview and not using autolayout, a autoresizing mask with flexible height and width should simply set the correct frame whenever the bounds of the superview change.

**Edit**

You are setting the subview's frame's origin to the origin of the superview - I suspect this is not intended. If the superview is moved from (0,0), this shifts the subview's origin by double the shift in relation to the window.

Comment: Yes you are correct auto resizing from size inspector is best way but i want place one calendar in center of this view.If i will use auto resizing then my calander will not get center value.

Comment: [_calendar setCenter:CGPointMake(_view1.frame.size.width / 2, _view1.frame.size.height / 2)];

Comment: This should not only be an issue for orientation changes. What about external display links? You should handle your layout in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Smit Saraiya: In general: If you center a subview in view1 you should calculate width view1.bounds insead of view1.frame.
Although this is not the root of your current problem.